# Handling HTTPError from imageio.imread

Tags: python-3.x, python-imageio

I'm using [imageio.imread](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html) and have a list of image URLs that can give 404 errors.

```
import imageio as io

try:
   imag = io.imread("http://static.booking.com/images/hotel/org/591/59160587.jpg")
except HTTPError as e:
   print("whatever")
```

Neither this or the following approaches are working for me:

#### Using urllib

```
import imageio as io
from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError

try:
   imag = io.imread("http://static.booking.com/images/hotel/org/591/59160587.jpg")
except BaseHTTPError as e:
   print("whatever")
```

#### Using requests.exceptions

```
import imageio as io
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

try:
   imag = io.imread("http://static.booking.com/images/hotel/org/591/59160587.jpg")
except HTTPError as e:
   print("whatever")
```

The Colab notebook below shows how both give `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uOOzJ4jDvYKe5zdFfxDkbcNRpxcjaOOj

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with

```
import imageio as io
from urllib import error

try:
   imag = io.imread("http://static.booking.com/images/hotel/org/591/59160587.jpg")
except error.HTTPError as e:
   print("whatever")
```